# How to print a user's error message when lr script fails

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, alm, vugen, microfocus

I am new to loadrunner. I know error handling part. But recently I came across a situation in which I use a parameter unique each iteration setting. This data is exuastive in nature i.e I cannot use them again.

Now in my script getting error where where it shouldn't be. Probably at the breaking point of the application. So I want to print that parameter whenever it fails anywhere in the script.

Any idea how to achieve this ?
Thanks in advnace.

Comment: see lr_output_message() combined with lr_eval_string()

Comment: @JamesPulley To use this solution we should know where my script might fails. but I don't know where my script fails.

Comment: IN VUGEN simply turn up the log level [f5]

Comment: @JamesPulley Can you share any article regarding this, or how to do it. ?

Comment: PCODE: (1) Check for expected result (2) if expected result fails, then lr_output_message(lr_eval_string("The data at point of failure was {my_parameter}"));

Comment: @JamesPulley sorry for asking once more, I am not getting this bit of code can you explain it or elaborate it ?.

Comment: You have an expected output upon success of the function.  If that expected output does not appear, then failure is assumed.  Take that value and output it to the output window on the controller using lr_output_message().  Or, if this generated an actual HTTP error (4xx-5xx) then look at the HTTP error log and pull the parameters off of the request parameters list